# How am I supposed to declare this C++ function?

Tags: c++

I have a C++ program with an undefined reference error on the call of a method in a class. As near as I can tell, the method is public and I'm calling it with a parameter declared the same as the method definition, but eclipse/gcc tells me it is undefined. I'm not used to C++, can someone please tell me what's wrong with the definition?

The main class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "AttenuationConfigurationTable.h"

int main()
{
  flash_entry_struct flash_array[] = { { 10, 20, 30, 40 }, { 50, 60, 70, 80 }, { -1, -1, -1, -1 } };

  // note: no undefined reference or any other error for the line with the class
  AttenuationConfigurationTable attConfigTable;
  // error appears for next line: undefined reference to ...load_attenuation_...
  attConfigTable.load_attenuation_calibration_table_from_flash(flash_array);
  return 0;
}
```

The class file:

```
#include "AttenuationConfigurationTable.h"
#include "flashEntryStruct.h"

AttenuationConfigurationTable::AttenuationConfigurationTable() {    }

AttenuationConfigurationTable::~AttenuationConfigurationTable() {    }

class Attenuation_configuration_table
{
  struct attenuation_voltages_struct
  {
    float att_value;
    float v1;
    float v2;
  } ;

  struct frequency_tables_struct
  {
    int frequency;
    attenuation_voltages_struct attenuation_voltages[100];
    int      voltages_count = 0;
  } ;

  frequency_tables_struct _frequency_tables[42];

  public:

  /************************************************************************/
  /* load the table in this object from the given flash memory address    */
  /************************************************************************/
  void load_attenuation_calibration_table_from_flash(flash_entry_struct memory_address[])
  {
    // bunch of logic here...
  }
};
```

The h file for the class:

```
#ifndef ATTENUATIONCONFIGURATIONTABLE_H_
#define ATTENUATIONCONFIGURATIONTABLE_H_

#include "flashEntryStruct.h"

class AttenuationConfigurationTable
{
public:
  AttenuationConfigurationTable();
  virtual ~AttenuationConfigurationTable();
  void load_attenuation_calibration_table_from_flash(flash_entry_struct flash_memory_address[]);
};

#endif /* ATTENUATIONCONFIGURATIONTABLE_H_ */
```

And, just for completeness, the h file defining the parameter structure:

```
#ifndef FLASHENTRYSTRUCT_H_
#define FLASHENTRYSTRUCT_H_

  struct flash_entry_struct
  {
    uint16_t  frequency;
    uint16_t  scaled_db;
    int8_t    v1_byte;
    int8_t    v2_byte;
  } ;

#endif /* FLASHENTRYSTRUCT_H_ */
```

EDIT: the error message itself:

```
Invoking: Cygwin C++ Linker
g++  -o "HelloCPP.exe" ./src/AttenuationConfigurationTable.o ./src/Hello2.o ./src/HelloCPP.o   
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: ./src/HelloCPP.o:/cygdrive/c/Users/ralph/files/programming/workspaces/HelloCPP/HelloCPP/Debug/../src/HelloCPP.cpp:15: undefined reference to `AttenuationConfigurationTable::load_attenuation_calibration_table_from_flash(flash_entry_struct*)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:58: HelloCPP.exe] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
```

Comment: Might be a linking issue. When you compile individual object files, do you link all of them together for a final executable?

Comment: `undefined reference to` mean the definition is missing from executable. Do you link all your obj file?

Comment: Is this the eclipse IDE giving you the error (a red squiggly line), or an actual compiler error you are getting when you go to compile the code?  Can we also get the exact wording from the error?

Comment: Though it shouldn’t be an error, passing an array to a function is the equivalent to just passing the address of the first element, so you don’t have context for the length of the array, you should also pass that in or end it with a known value, so you can possibly not crash later… or better yet would be a reference to a std::list or std::vector…

Comment: @lubgr I put all this in eclipse and hit control-B - don't know another way to build it.

Comment: @NathanOliver edited the question to include the error itself, should have done that in the first place, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare `AttenuationConfigurationTable` in the header file with the `load_attenuation_calibration_table_from_flash` function, but then the function with the same name in the implementation file is inside the definition for *another class*, `Attenuation_configuration_table`.

Take the implementation for `load_attenuation_calibration_table_from_flash` out of the class definition for `Attenuation_configuration_table` in your cpp file, and define it instead as

```
void AttenuationConfigurationTable::load_attenuation_calibration_table_from_flash(/* ... */) {
// ...
}
```

This is the same syntax already used for the constructor and destructor in that file.

In the end, your header should look something like this:

```
class AttenuationConfigurationTable
{
public:
  AttenuationConfigurationTable();
  virtual ~AttenuationConfigurationTable();
  void load_attenuation_calibration_table_from_flash(flash_entry_struct flash_memory_address[]);

private:
  struct attenuation_voltages_struct
  {
    float att_value;
    float v1;
    float v2;
  } ;

  struct frequency_tables_struct
  {
    int frequency;
    attenuation_voltages_struct attenuation_voltages[100];
    int voltages_count;
  } ;
  
  frequency_tables_struct _frequency_tables[42];
};
```

and your cpp file should look something like this:

```
AttenuationConfigurationTable::AttenuationConfigurationTable() {    }

AttenuationConfigurationTable::~AttenuationConfigurationTable() {    }

void AttenuationConfigurationTable::load_attenuation_calibration_table_from_flash(/* params */) {
  // body
}
```

Comment: I  tried that, but the references to the structs I declared inside the class then got flagged as undeclared. If there's a way to reference structs that I want to keep private to the class but declare the method outside the class, I'd be glad to know about it (again, this is not a language in which I'm fluent), but absent that I need to keep it in the class def. Thanks for catching the name change, that sounds like it.

Comment: You can declare the structs in the header file as well, or simply declare them in the cpp file but outside of a `class`. One of them is used to declare a field though, so I'd recommend declaring them in the header and putting `frequency_tables_struct _frequency_tables[42];` in the header's class declaration.

Comment: Clear, direct, solved my problem, extra effort after my addtiional question in comments -- and no suggestion that I change my problem, though if you had, at least you would have been answering me as well. I'd upvote twice if I could -- thanks. I'm compiling without errors! On to the debugging!

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with debugging :)